# Arraylist Integer to Drawable Images in android

Tags: java, android

imageList should be arraylist

and in my bean how i can convert it into Drawable and 
how can we set it to the parameters in bean

below given class is my bean

```
public class ParkPhotoFetchBean {
    private int parkPics;
    arraylist should come here
```

and we need to change it into drawable so 
how can i set it by changing it to drawableimage

```
    void ParkPhotoFetchBin(int parkPics){
        this.parkPics = parkPics;
    }

    public int getParkPics() {
        return parkPics;
    }
getter and setter
    public void setParkPics(int parkPics) {
        this.parkPics = parkPics;
    }

}
```

another class is

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DividerItemDecoration;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.project.parkingapplication.adapter.HorizontalRecyclerAdapter;
import com.project.parkingapplication.entities.ParkPhotoFetchBean;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class BookingDetail extends AppCompatActivity {
    private List<ParkPhotoFetchBean> parkingPhotoList = new ArrayList<>();
    RecyclerView rvContainer;
    Activity activity;
    HorizontalRecyclerAdapter myRecyclerViewAdapter;
    com.project.parkingapplication.entities.ParkPhotoFetchBean myRecyclerBean;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_booking_detail);
        activity = this;
        rvContainer.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(BookingDetail.this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL));
        myRecyclerViewAdapter = new HorizontalRecyclerAdapter(parkingPhotoList, this);
        LinearLayoutManager horizontalLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(BookingDetail.this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        rvContainer.setLayoutManager(horizontalLayoutManager);
        rvContainer.setAdapter(myRecyclerViewAdapter);
        populatePhotoList();

    }

    private void populatePhotoList() {
        ArrayList<Integer> imagesList = new ArrayList();
        imagesList.add(R.drawable.image1);
        imagesList.add(R.drawable.image2);
        imagesList.add(R.drawable.image3);
        imagesList.add(R.drawable.image4);
        imagesList.add(R.drawable.car);

        ParkPhotoFetchBean parkPhotoFetchBean = new ParkPhotoFetchBean(imagesList); //image List should be array list and in my //bean how i can convert it into drawable

    }

    private void mappingWidget() {
        rvContainer = findViewById(R.id.rv_booking_detail_image_slider);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Can you please tell your purpose also, so one can tell you best approach.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Instead of this:

```
ParkPhotoFetchBean parkPhotoFetchBean = new ParkPhotoFetchBean(imagesList);
```

Write:

```
for(int i=0; i<imagesList.size(); i++) 
{
    parkingPhotoList.add(new ParkPhotoFetchBean(imagesList.get(i)))
}
myRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Now, you can use `parkingPhotoList` in your activity which contains your images from the bean class. You don't have to pass your arraylist to your bean class. You images will be displayed in `RecyclerView`

Comment: my imageList should be of ArraLIst<Parkphotofetchbean> or arraylist<Integer>?

Comment: ImageList must be Arraylist of Integer, Your program is correct, just replace your one line with for loop as shown in my solution. @RudreshMehta